# Eagerly loading a circular association

Tags: sqlalchemy

I following is a minimal example of a many-to-many association. My goal is to load a single record of `X` and also eagerly load the instances of `Y` which are in the record's `ys` list **as well as** the instances of `X` which are in any of those instance's `xs` list.

```
class X(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'x'
    xid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ys = relationship('Z', back_populates='x', lazy='joined')


class Y(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'y'
    yid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    xs = relationship('Z', back_populates='y', lazy='joined')


class Z(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'z'
    xid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('x.xid'), primary_key=True)
    yid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('y.yid'), primary_key=True)
    x = relationship('X', back_populates='ys', lazy='joined')
    y = relationship('Y', back_populates='xs', lazy='joined')
```

My goal is to produce the following result:

```
expected = [{
    'xid': 1,
    'ys': [
        {'yid': 101, 'xs': [{'xid': 1}, {'xid': 2}, {'xid': 3}]},
        {'yid': 102, 'xs': [{'xid': 1}, {'xid': 2}]},
        {'yid': 104, 'xs': [{'xid': 1}, {'xid': 4}]},
    ],
}]
```

The SQL statement to achieve this is fairly straightforward:

```
SELECT x.xid, y.yid, x2.xid FROM x
JOIN z       ON z.xid  = x.xid JOIN y       ON z.yid  = y.yid  ; Fetch Ys
JOIN z as z2 ON z2.yid = y.yid JOIN x as x2 ON z2.xid = x2.xid ; Fetch Xs (depth 2)
WHERE x.xid = 1
```

My issue is determining how to create a SQLAlchemy query that will either (a) allow me to execute this raw query and map it correctly to the right model instances, or (b) massage the query (with some combination of join and contains_eager calls) so that it knows how to actually *use the joins that it's generating* so that it doesn't explode into n+1 queries.

The proper query is generated by the following, but I cannot manage to get the depth 2 X instances to load from this query (the data is loaded lazily by a second select).

```
a = aliased(Z)
b = aliased(X)
q = X.query.filter(X.xid==1).join(X.ys).join(Z.y).join(a, Y.xs).join(b, Z.x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the eager-loading mechanism works is, you need to specify a *path* to the relationship you want to load as well as how you want to load it. The path is basically which relationships to follow, in sequence, in order to find the relationship that you want. In your particular example, the correct thing to do is this:

```
q = session.query(X).filter(X.xid == 1) \
           .join(X.ys) \
           .join(Z.y) \
           .join(a, Y.xs) \
           .join(b, Z.x) \
           .options(
               contains_eager(X.ys),
               contains_eager(X.ys, Z.y),
               contains_eager(X.ys, Z.y, Y.xs, alias=a),
               contains_eager(X.ys, Z.y, Y.xs, Z.x, alias=b),
           )
```

Each `contains_eager` specifies a load on a single relationship, with the path (`X.ys, Z.y, Y.xs, Z.x`) specifying where the relationship is, and the `contains_eager` as well as `alias` specifying how to load the relationship. This is quite verbose, but fortunately SQLAlchemy provides a shortcut that lets you chain them together, like this:

```
.options(contains_eager(X.ys).contains_eager(Z.y).contains_eager(Y.xs, alias=a).contains_eager(Z.x, alias=b))
```

If you're using `.join` for the explicit goal of then doing `contains_eager`, you might as well just use `joinedload` instead:

```
q = session.query(X).filter(X.xid==1) \
           .options(joinedload(X.ys).joinedload(Z.y).joinedload(Y.xs).joinedload(Z.x))
```

In your particular case, joining like this may not be efficient if your branch factor is high, i.e. if your `X.ys` and `Y.xs` contain a maximum of `n` entries, then your database has to send you `n^2` copies of *every single row in X*. For this reason, `subqueryload` is often the right choice for one-to-many relationships (this is not always the case; the trade off is between the number of queries, i.e. latency, against the amount of data in each query, i.e. throughput, so profile to find out):

```
q = session.query(X).filter(X.xid==1) \
           .options(subqueryload(X.ys).joinedload(Z.y).subqueryload(Y.xs).joinedload(Z.x))
```

Finally, if all you want is a many-to-many relationship, why not just configure a many-to-many relationship in the first place?

Comment: Awesome - my issue was that I was only using the _last_ `contains_eager` call that you have in the first example. I thought that would be enough to encode the path.